# Editar texto desde el front end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo estos paneles en Bootstrap, con texto escrito directamente de html, es decir sin traerlo de base de datos..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la pregunta es, hay alguna forma de editar lo que tiene escrito directamente desde el front end, es decir sin tener que hacer un formulario mediante php y guardar los datos para luego traerlos de la base de datos?

gracias.

Comment: Si no te importa que los cambios no se guarden podrías hacerlo con javascript.

Comment: vuejs más rapido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr con JQuery, a través de un elemento (por ejemplo un botón) que te permita editar el texto, es decir, no podrías simplemente dar click sobre el texto y empezar a editar; la solución es la siguiente:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'), isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
    $('div').prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
})
```

```css
.editable{ background:#EAEAEA}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Texto editable...</div>
<br>
<button>Editar Texto</button>
```

Al presionar el botón te permitirá editar y al volver a presionarlo te bloqueará (como viene por defecto).

Espero te sirva.

Comment: El editor de html no me permite modificar el orden pero te explico: el primer bloque va dentro de las etiquetas <script></sctript>. El segundo bloque va dentro de las etiquetas <style></style>. Y el tercer bloque iría tal cual. Todo en un mismo archivo con extensión html

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo en Javascript.

```
<h1 id="mi-h1">
  Texto definido desde HTML
</h1>

<div>
  <input id="input" type="text">
  <button id="button">
    Cambiar texto
  </button>
</div>
```

En mi html tengo una etiqueta `<h1>` con texto definido desde el código html. El cual será cambiado con lo escrito en el `input` al momento de dar click en el botón.

```
let h1 = document.getElementById('mi-h1');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = () => {
  let texto = input.value;
  h1.innerHTML=texto;
}
```

Declaro unas variables haciendo referencia a los elementos html. Al hacer click en el botón se almacena lo escrito en el input y se pone en la etiqueta `<h1>`.